# Fire a event on change of any radio button on the from

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have form which has two groups of radio buttons,onchange of any of the bottons,i need a event to be fired,say hide something.How to do that on javascript,(using dojo can i do that)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up onclick handlers on HTML radio buttons?  The handler can simply flip the visibility (or even animation) on another element via CSS.  Dojo adds some sugar you can use to modify css, such as dojo.style but it's effectively the same.  The onclick handler can be defined directly on the element markup or attached with dojo.connect.

Dijit's [radio button](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/RadioButton.html#dijit-form-radiobutton) widget is just an incremental enhancement on the basic HTML radio form element which provides some theming, but the same applies.